# HTML/CSS: Middle Vertical Align

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm trying to **middle vertical align** my site's logo with my navigation link list.  I've tried adding "vertical-align: middle" to my div columns, but nothing happens.  Right now my logo and my navigations look kinda weird and is just floating around.  Any help on this would be great.

HTML:

```
   <div class="sixteen columns clearfix">
    <div class="five columns">
      <a href="{{ shop.url }}" title="{{ shop.name }}">
      {% if settings.use_logo %}
        <img src="{{ 'logo.png' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ shop.name }}" />
      {% else %}
        {{ shop.name }}
      {% endif %}
    </a>
      </div>
    <div class="eleven columns">
    <div id="mobile_nav"></div>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul id="menu">
        {% for link in linklists[settings.main_linklist].links %}
          {% if linklists[link.handle] == empty %}
            <li><a href="{{ link.url }}" title="{{ link.title }}" {% if link.active %}class="active"{% endif %}>{{ link.title }}</a></li>
          {% else %}
            <li><a href="{{ link.url }}" title="{{ link.title }}" {% if link.active %}class="active"{% endif %} {% for link in linklists[link.handle].links %}{% if link.active %}class="active"{% endif %}{% endfor %}>{{ link.title }} 
              <span class="arrow">&or;</span></a> 
              <ul>
                {% for link in linklists[link.handle].links %}
                  {% if linklists[link.handle] == empty %}
                    <li><a href="{{ link.url }}" title="{{ link.title }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
                  {% else %}
                  <li><a href="{{ link.url }}" title="{{ link.title }}">{{ link.title }} <span class="arrow"> &gt;</span></a> 
                    <ul>
                      {% for link in linklists[link.handle].links %}                        
                        <li><a href="{{ link.url }}" title="{{ link.title }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            </li>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Column CSS:

```
  .column, .columns { 
float: left; 
display: inline; 
margin-left: 10px; 
margin-right: 10px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here's how it currently looks like:

[image]

Need to move it to the middle:

[image]

Comment: Any chance you could provide a demo at http://jsfiddle.net so that we can play with it (without having to read past the server-side code in your html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Specify the parent container as `position: relative` or `position: absolute`.
> 2. Specify a fixed height on the child container.
> 3. Set `position: absolute` and `top: 50%` on the child container to move the top down to the middle of the parent.
> 4. Set `margin-top: -yy` where `yy` is half the height of the child container to offset the item up.

(http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/)

- Either relatively position `.columns`  *(`position: relative`)* or absolutely position it  *(`position: absolute`)*
- Give `.column` a **`height` value**
- Absolutely position `.column`  *(`position: absolute`)*, and give it `top: 50%`
- Give `.column` a top margin of the negative of half its **`height` value**  *(`margin-top: -yy` where yy is half of the height of `.column`)*

Answer (score 0):

As you have already used `vertical-align: middle` in class; so by just adding `display: table-cell` property your problem must solved.

**Note:** There are many ways to align content or div vertically.. using `line-height` (condition is only apply for first line), `padding-top`, `table-cell` and giving `absolute` position.